# adonis: Error right-hand-side of formula has no usable terms

Tags: r, vegan

I have this chao distance matrix based on all fungi abundances:

```
      CR10      CR11      CR13      CR14      CR17      CR18      CR19
CR11 0.4531840                                                            
CR13 0.4288178 0.4624915                                                  
CR14 0.5903908 0.5466617 0.4942469                                        
CR17 0.4784990 0.3387325 0.6136265 0.5779121                              
CR18 0.7649840 0.7537409 0.7526077 0.5632825 0.4153391                    
CR19 0.3772907 0.4579895 0.3208187 0.3706775 0.5644193 0.7380274          
CR20 0.4598706 0.5529427 0.6424340 0.6690386 0.3855154 0.5509150 0.6406800
```

and the table with 33 environmental variables for the same plots.

when I run:

```
fungAbundAdonis <- lapply(colnames(env2), function(x) {
  form <- as.formula(paste("OTU.table2", x, sep="~")) 
  z <- adonis(form, data = env2, permutations=999)
  return(data.frame(env = rownames(z$aov.tab), Rsq = z$aov.tab$R2,P = z$aov.tab$P))}
)
```

I get this error:

> Error in adonis(form, data = env2, permutations = 999) :
>   right-hand-side of formula has no usable terms.

I don't understand why because when I use the same script with the distance matrix of plots from 1 to 9 and 12 15 and 16 and the environmental table for these plots it works fine. Does anybody know what the source of the error could be?
thanks!

Comment: vegan 2.5-x (release) or 2.6-0 (devel)? These will behave differently in this case. However, it seems that the reason is that  you have no usable terms in `env2`. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has no reproducible example, and I have to guess. However, I can reproduce your error message if the variable is *constant* in the right-hand-side. This may happen when you subset `env2` and in that selected subset a variable has only one value. (This only concerns vegan 2.5-x or release version: vegan 2.6-0 will not give an error message.)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I have vegan 2-4-4, and you are definitely right, I have constant variables in the right-hand side.